# Where This Code Belongs? MVC & ORM

Tags: model-view-controller, orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm reading unofficial Kohana 3.0 docs at the moment. Where this code belongs? In controller or in model (`class Model_MyName extends ORM` model?)? I think that it should go in model. Am I right? If that so... why is it on controller and how to implement it in model (do I need to change something in `save()` method?)?

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', 1);
$user->name = 'Joe';
$user->values($_POST);
if ($user->check()) {
    $user->save();
} else {
    $errors = $user->validate()->errors();
}
```

Code taken from [here](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=orm) under "Model Validation".

Comment: I have found [this](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/4956/x) topic about the discussion so far, but I would love to hear your thoughts too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It belongs to the controller. This code is clearly using the 'user' model from ORM factory.

$user is an instance of the 'user' model. In your case the models are being provided by Kohana's ORM.

Comment: But its not business logic. Its application logic and that's why should be located in model. Am I wrong?

Comment: Its not business logic, but controller is supposed to process information from model to views and views to models. This is exactly what this code is doing. Getting the values from `$_POST` (view) to model. The model exposes the `values` function allowing the controller to do so.
The model has also exposed a save() functionality, and the controller is executing the user's command probably on a `save` functionality on the view.